# Ubuntu touch on vegetalte (BQ Aquaris E5 HD LTE)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, aquaris

Is it possible to install ubuntu touch on an Aquaris E5 LTE model? I don't actually need the LTE to work since I only have a 3G provider. Can I trick my phone into displaying as a vegetahd in fastboot mode so I can use the system image server to run the update? (edit: right now the device identifies itself as MSM8916)

[Terminal Screenshot ubuntu-device-flash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjfpi.jpg)

I am comfortable with the risks this causes to the phone in terms of bricking it. I have already fixed countless boot loops and other problems with this phone, and honestly I just want it for ubuntu and its not worth much more to me than a paperweight without it.

Thanks!